# Making ubuntu recognize devices in usb hub

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-modem

Some devices like keyboard works fine on a cheap USB hub I bought, but I'm trying to put a USB Modem on the same hub and it fails, but if I put directly to my notebook it works fine.

My findings so far:

`lsusb` shows my USB modem as "Unknown Manufacturer hub":

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 0cf3:e005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2c01 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 1c9e:98ff OMEGA TECHNOLOGY Keyboard Hub
Bus 001 Device 058: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 056: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4G Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I plug the USB modem I get this from `dmesg`:

```
[  +0,000003] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001094] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000122] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,413173] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101104] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000005] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000003] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001181] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000122] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,365607] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 26
[  +0,023730] usb 1-2.2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2-port2: failed to disable port power
[  +0,079775] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,100949] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000008] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000005] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001275] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000091] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,365617] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 31
[  +0,023818] usb 1-2.2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  +0,000005] usb 1-2.2-port2: failed to disable port power
[  +0,079672] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101122] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000005] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000003] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001347] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000156] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,365261] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 36
[  +0,019916] usb 1-2.2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2-port2: failed to disable port power
[  +0,079775] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,100975] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000006] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001247] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000084] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,365724] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 41
[  +0,019775] usb 1-2.2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2-port2: failed to disable port power
[  +0,079791] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101193] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000006] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000003] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001321] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000127] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,369393] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 46
[  +0,019740] usb 1-2.2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  +0,000005] usb 1-2.2-port2: failed to disable port power
[  +0,083775] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 51 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101092] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000006] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001412] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000182] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,465403] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 51
[  +0,019599] usb 1-2.2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2-port2: failed to disable port power
[  +0,079807] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101686] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000006] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001440] hub 1-2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000108] hub 1-2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,084618] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101979] usb 1-2.3: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[  +0,004366] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1c9e, idProduct=98ff, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  +0,000006] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  +0,000003] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: USB Modem
[  +0,000003] usb 1-2.3: SerialNumber: 1234567890ABCDEF
[  +0,309238] usb 1-2.2.2: new full-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,000443] usb-storage 1-2.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,000145] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2.3:1.0
[  +0,000093] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  +0,001772] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  +0,103439] usb 1-2.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000006] usb 1-2.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.2.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  +0,001477] hub 1-2.2.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000151] hub 1-2.2.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,897740] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,000866] scsi 2:0:0:1: CD-ROM            USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,000829] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  +0,003979] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[  +0,000007] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[  +0,016596] sr 2:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  +0,000097] sr 2:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  +0,009099] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  +0,126863] usb 1-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,101838] usb 1-2.3: device firmware changed
[  +0,000259] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000008] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 02 1b fc 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000008] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 552944 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000264] usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 57
[  +0,013331] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000011] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 02 1b fc 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000009] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 552944 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000011] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 69118, async page read
[  +0,000211] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000008] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000007] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000071] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000007] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000006] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000007] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000065] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000007] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000005] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000006] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000055] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000007] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000005] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000005] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000057] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000007] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000005] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000005] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000058] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000006] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000005] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000005] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000053] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000007] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000005] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000005] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000053] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000007] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000005] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000005] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000049] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,000047] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0,214899] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,105040] usb 1-2.3: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[  +0,000922] usb 1-2.3: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[  +0,000005] usb 1-2.3: can't read configurations, error -71
[  +0,077926] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,104540] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1c9e, idProduct=98ff, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  +0,000007] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  +0,000004] usb 1-2.3: SerialNumber: 1234567890ABCDEF
[  +0,004444] usb 1-2.3: can't set config #1, error -71
```

The first error being:

```
[  +0,101838] usb 1-2.3: device firmware changed
[  +0,000259] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000008] sr 2:0:0:1: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 02 1b fc 00 00 02 00
[  +0,000008] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 552944 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Lots of errors. The usb modem gets recognized by Ubuntu but then immediately "shuts down".

Any tips how to debug this further?

I shouldn't have saved on this one and bought a decent USB Hub.

Comment: Is the USB HUB powered ? Is the modem ? Maybe it requires more power than the HUB can provide =

Comment: Hubs take power; if it's un-powered it'll be sharing power that the devices plugged into it will also be sharing... ie. un-powered hubs mean less power is available for devices and the power can drop below operating threshold (ie. *normally working devices can no longer operate correctly*)...   Debugging this requires multi-meter and is off-topic here

Comment: The USB hub must be a powered hub... ie: one that has its own external power supply.

Comment: Yes, it's powered guys @guiverc

Comment: @heynnema its powered

Comment: Try connecting the USB hub to a different USB port on the computer. Try a different powered USB hub.

Comment: Does it provide the correct power; eg. USB 1 was a 150mAh I think; USB 1.1 & 2.0 were 500mAh and USB 3.0 is 900mAh - ie. correctly powered for your USB modem...

Comment: Yes it does @guiverc, its a hb t69 hub 10 port hub, you can check out the specs

Comment: @heynnema tried that, nothing

Comment: The behavior is typical for under powered USB hubs, or hubs with too much current draw plugged in. Do the numbers! How much current (in milliamps) is being provided by the hub's power supply, how much current (milliamps) is needed by all the plugged-in devices, and the hub itself?

Comment: You tried a different powered USB hub?

Comment: @waltinator Since the power comes from the USB Hub itself, shouldn't I discard this hypothesis? Since the power plug comes attached to the usb hub itself.

Comment: If the USB hub really IS "powered", it has a wall-wart with fine print on it. Find "Output: 5V ###mA". If the hub gets its power from the computer, it's not "powered".

Comment: Its plugged on the wall in its own power source @waltinator

Comment: Unplug the power source from the wall and look on each face for the specifications. You have responded many times without ever providing the requested information. Are you a noise source (to be ignored)?

Comment: @waltinator I might not be understanding what you are asking then. You said "If the hub gets its power from the computer, it's not powered", and I replied that it's plugged on the wall, not on PC". What you mean "look on each face for the specifications"? There is nothing written on the hub itself. I'm pretty sure it's not a general power issue, as I can put as many usb pen drives I want and it detects fine, the problem seem to be related with usb modems. I might be wrong, tho... I just don't know how to debug it further.